# How to get correct list numbering with code blocks items in Org-babel?

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-babel

Here is a minimal working example of Org file for LaTeX export:

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

* A list with R source blocks
1. This is the first item.
#+begin_src R :results output :session *R* :exports both
x <- 2
print(2*x)
#+end_src
2. This is the second item.

* Local Variables :noexport:
Local Variables:
org-latex-listings:nil
End:
```

Here is the output I get:

[image]

As you can see, the numbering of items in org lists is "broken" if one of the items contains a source block. Is there a way to avoid that, and to have the second item correctly labeled "2." ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert three spaces before `#+begin_src` and `#+end_src` to shift the source block on the same level as the items. You do not need to indent the source code.

Without indent Org thinks the source block starts a new paragraph below the list.

Comment: Many thanks, I really missed that in the documentation... It works, but I had to indent *both* `#+begin_src` and `#+end_src` lines. If I indent only the 'begin' line, it still does not work. Strange. But thanks again!

Comment: @Philopolis Thanks for the correction. I can reproduce that `#+end_src` also must be indented.I think I missed to update the pdf-view when I tested it.